# javascript, unexpected token {

Tags: javascript, if-statement, for-loop, syntax

Okay, I have a very basic syntax error that I'm having issues resolving. Apparently I missed something very basic and important on the code academy class I can't seem to resolve. I'll post the code below. It should be obvious what I'm trying to do within.

The error = "Syntax Error: Unexpected token {"

The goal, write my own code incorporating for loops, if/else, and functions.

```
var data = ["love", "peace", "anger", "war"]

for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
  if (i <=2){
    console.log("life is" + " " +data[i]);
  }
  else if (i <=4){
    console.log("Strife is" + " " + data[i]);
  }
  else (i = 5){
    console.log("That's all for now");
  }
}
```

Comment: else does not take a condition. Remove `(i = 5)` Also, note that `=` is assignment and `==` is check

Comment: If/else with multiple conditions consider using switch statement.

Comment: @saj switch isn't appropriate for these types of conditions.

Comment: Thank you @karthikr, that helped a lot. I should have picked up on the assignment sooner. I removed the "=" signs from the if/else statements, along with the variable check in the else statement and it worked.

Comment: "I removed the = signs from the if/else statements" There was nothing wrong with the other two, if they were what you wanted.. `<=` means 'less than or equals' and `<` means 'less than'

Comment: Revisiting that problem. I removed the else statement and placed the final console log outside of the for loop. Other than that all four statements still printed from the if/else loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem, as pointed out, is that `else` does *not* take a condition which makes sense as the else body is run when all the *other* corresponding if/else-if conditionals failed.

Thus JavaScript (not requiring braces around if/else-bodies) is parsing it as so:

```
else Statement
```

More specifically it starts parsing it as an [ExpressionStatement](http://es5.github.io/#A.4), `(i = 5)`, followed by an invalid `{`. It is invalid for the same reason the following is invalid:

```
i = 5 { }
```

Statements must be separated by semicolons - explicitly or via [automatic semicolon insertion](http://inimino.org/~inimino/blog/javascript_semicolons). The former is not done and the latter does not apply in the given code.

Comment: Yep, karthikr was able to point me in the right direction. I was able to resolve the coding errors after that. Before hand my researching wasn't very helpful.